# webdriver container in circleci for testing

Tags: django, selenium-webdriver, docker, continuous-integration, circleci

**Problem**

I have a [CircleCI](https://circleci.com) continuous integration for my django application. I would like to use a [standalone chrome](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/master/StandaloneChrome) selenium node container to run my UI tests. The following setup works locally:

- **Launch django server in the background:**

  ```
  python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8081 &
  ```
- **Run the webdriver container:**

  ```
  docker run --net='host' --name selenium -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
  ```
- **Run test:**

  ```
  from fabric.operations import local
  from selenium import webdriver
  @given('I have a web browser')
  def browser():
      return webdriver.Remote(
          command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
          desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)


  @when('I open the main page')
  def view_main(browser):
      assert "backend.fail" in local("curl http://localhost:8081/", capture=True)
      browser.maximize_window()
      browser.get("http://localhost:8081/")
      return browser
  ```

  `curl http://localhost:8081/` is run in the context of the CircleCI shell, and succeeds, whereas `browser.get("http://localhost:8081/")` is run from the docker container running webdriver and fails.

**Question**

How can I make my docker container see my django server on `localhost:8081` on CircleCI?

**Research**

I read in the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#container-networking) that `--net=host` puts the host and docker client on the same network stack, and it works locally in a vagrant vm.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512772/setting-up-multiple-docker-containers-and-mongodb-to-run-in-circleci) which explores communication between multiple docker containers and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213195/running-docker-container-tests-on-circleci) which handles a general setup of docker tests on CircleCI, but none address the visibility of the host from a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

After some digging and using CircleCI's excellent `ssh` debugging tool, it turned out that the reason for the failure was not `--net='host'` but rather the selenium container failing to start.

It silently failed because

```
unable to start xvfb
unable to start xvfb
unable to start xvfb
unable to start xvfb
```

Then I googled *"selenium circleci"* and it turned out that CircleCI has a native `xfvb` running on `:99` and `chromedriver` [preinstalled](https://circleci.com/docs/environment#browsers):

> CircleCI runs graphical programs in a virtual framebuffer, using **xvfb**.
>   This means programs like **Selenium**, Capybara, Jasmine, and other
>   testing tools which require a browser **will work perfectly**, just like
>   they do when you use them locally.

I changed my test to:

```
@given('I have a web browser')
def browser():
    try:
        return webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    except:
        return webdriver.Chrome()
```

And now my tests pass.